# Accelerometer gyrometer for radxa board - i2c configurable addresses vs spi

Tags: spi, i2c, addressing

I am looking for an accelerometer/gyrometer that has configurable address.
It should run on a radxa rock board using i2c,
or
some spi solution.
I am using that board (PRO)
http://radxa.com/Rock/specification
History:
I've tried that sensor for the last three days http://www.pololu.com/product/2468/resources until I noticed that the radxa already uses most of it's i2c addresses from all of the 4 busses. It's the first time I am working on a "non software only" project. Already got some experience but not many. That's why I was looking for the error in my code/checked if the sensor was broken etc.
In the end I noticed that the the radxa already uses the address that the sensor has. (It uses most of the address)
Outprint from i2cdetect (i2cdetect -y BUS_NUMBER)

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 
10: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 
20: 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f 
40: 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 
70: 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
```

That's why I am looking for a sensors that have completely configurable address (not just high and low for one bit) or some device that I can put in front of sensors to change the addresses.

If I want to evaluate the data in 1kHz I might should go spi anyway?
Cheers :)

Comment: 1kHz is *sloooow*. SPI is massive overkill (SPI speeds pick up where I\$^2\$C speeds leave off).

Comment: Please run `dmesg -n 3 && i2cdetect -y -r BUS_NUMBER` to scan the i2c devices, BUS_NUMBER is the i2c bus number. The i2c scan result is not the correct output, there could not be so many i2c devices.

Comment: You're asking someone to run code, without reference to a documentation. It would be preferable to provide some reference on this command, so that people can verify that you're not hacking their device when they run this. Besides that, I don't really see how this is an answer to the question. Once you've earned more reputation, you could add it as a comment.

Comment: I used i2cdetect -y BUS_NUMBER to outprint it, not sure what dmesg -n does, havent found any docs about "-n"

Comment: To anwser my own question, dmesg -n 3 sets the loglevel. If I run `dmesg -n 3 && i2cdetect -y -r BUS_NUMBER` the list is empty, except the first time I call it. In the first run 76 and 36 showed up, but if I call it again the values are all "null". Dont know what 36 should be as the values of the sensor are `1E` and `32`. If I run`dmesg -n 3 && i2cdetect -y -q BUS_NUMBER` the list is full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, as someone might do the same mistakes:
 1. i2cdetect -y -r 0, only 0 is for "public" devices. -r outprints the results you want to have
 2. Radxa needs 3V connected to Vin and Vdd 
 3. I2c is maybe fast enough,if you use the kernel (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451233/i2c-set-clock-freq-radxa-rock-pro)